# How can I speed up VB copy

Tags: vb.net

I'm running the following loop successfully when the number of items is low. However, when run against a larger list on the ListView, it seems to be taking way too long. I tested it with a list of 8,700 files and it took about two hours to complete. Is there something I can do to speed this up? I guess that removing the check for the Cancel button would help but I would like to keep that there for usability. As I've mentioned in earlier posts, I'm pretty new to Visual Basic so please provide lots of explanation with your suggestions. Thanks. Here's the code:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To m_CountTo

        ' Has the background worker be told to stop?
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            ' Set Cancel to True
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        'Select the row from the LVFiles ListView, then move the first column (0) into strSourceFilePath and the last
        ' column (3) into strDestFilePath. Execute the CopyFile method to copy the file.

        LVFiles.Items(i).Selected = True
        strSourceFilePath = LVFiles.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(0).Text
        strDestFilePath = LVFiles.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(3).Text
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strSourceFilePath, strDestFilePath, overwrite:=False)

        ' Report The progress of the Background Worker.
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt((i / m_CountTo) * 100))
        ' Me.LabelStatus.Text = FormatPercent((i + 1) / (intLVIndex + 1), 2) ' Show Percentage in Label
        SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.LabelStatus, FormatPercent(i / m_CountTo, 2))

    Next
```

Comment: Removing the cancel test will not significantly improve the performance. How long does it take to copy the 8700 files if you use Windows Explorer (drag-and-drop, copy-paste, etc)? if it's about the same amount of time, then the performance issue isn't in your program.

Comment: If you comment out the line with CopyFile, how long does it take?

Comment: Assuming that the posted code is running in the the `BackgroundWorker1.DoWork` event handler, how are you not getting an __System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'LVFiles' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'__ error?

Comment: you can also speed up the procedure if you remove  `LVFiles.Items(i).Selected = True` updating UI consumes more system resources especially when it has a big data

Comment: MarkL - If I do a drag and drop it takes about 15 minutes. Andrew Morton - If I comment out the CopyFile line and run it, it takes about 1 hour 15 minutes. TnTinMn - I'm wondering if this is part of the problem. I'm using a dirty fix where I turn off the check for Illegal cross-thread calls. I don't know if the error is still generated and then ignored or what. I know I should probably be using a delegate or something but after some investigation it seemed beyond my current talent level. Mo Khalefa - I'll try this.

Comment: Mo Khalefa - I don't see how I can get around having that line in the code. I need the values that it reads to set some parameters for the CopyFile statement.

Comment: keco - the SetLabelText_ThreadSafe sub is the delegate that I believe allows the status to be updated on the UI. If I were to put the source data in a variable length array instead of a ListView, does anyone think this might speed things up? I'm afraid to make the change unless there's a good chance it would help.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin I deleted my comment since I didn't looked at the code properly. Instead of `CopyFile` try using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` for a speed test to compare your code and my suggested code.

Answer (score 1):

The Backgroundworker encapsulates a new thread. You cannot directly access controls that are created in another thread. If you do you will get an `InvalidOperationException` because of a cross-thread operation. The Backgroundworker however offers some functionality to share data (or access to controls) between threads. You should use them.

```
    Private Sub StartBGW_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBGW.Click
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To m_CountTo
            dict.Add(Me.LVFiles.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text,
                     Me.LVFiles.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
        Next

        Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(dict)
    End Sub
```

First we prepare a dictionary that contains the source as `Key` and the target as `Value`. This object is given to the `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter.

Now comes the essential part:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim counter As Integer = -1
        Dim dict = DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        For Each kvp In dict
            counter += 1

            ' Has the background worker be told to stop?
            If Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
                ' Set Cancel to True
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If

           'Select the row from the LVFiles ListView, then move the first column (0) into strSourceFilePath and the last
           ' column (3) into strDestFilePath. Execute the CopyFile method to copy the file.

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, overwrite:=False)

            ' Report The progress of the Background Worker.
            Me.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt((counter / m_CountTo) * 100), counter)
        Next
    End Sub
```

We don't access the `ListView` anymore. Instead we use the dictionary that is given to us as a parameter through `e.Argument`. Theres also a slight difference in the `BackgroundWorker1.ReportsProgress` line. There's a second parameter I have used to pass the current index to the `ProgressChanged` event which can be obtained via `e.UserState`.

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Me.LVFiles.Items(Convert.ToInt32(e.UserState)).Selected = True
        Me.LabelStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
    End Sub
```

This event is designed to be raised with a SynchronizationContext of the calling thread, in this case the UI thread. Here we can safely access any control and update them. The index is passed as `e.UserState`, so we can access the relevant item and set their `Selected` property to true.

---

The biggest improvement comes from the change of `Me.LVFiles.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(0).Text` to `Me.LVFiles.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text`. I'm not a professional, but it seems that `SelectedItems` isn't a real list. Instead it iterates through every item using the SendMessage API until the desired index is reached. This is why it takes longer the higher your index is. Everytime it starts with the first item and iterates through them. Lot of operations.

The second improvement is the separation of code that access UI controls. It's all done in one method now. More clear and readable.

**Update**: @Enigmativity mentioned that `SelectedListViewItemCollection` implements `IList` and therefore is a real list. Even though it has no underlying list containing all selected items like you have in `ListViewItemCollection`. My point was to say, that accessing a single element is more complicated.

Comment: Dharman - Thank you for the clear explanations. This has made it something I can refer to in the future. One problem - the progress status isn't changing at all even though in looking at the code it seems it should. Also it sped it up from 2 hours on a large test directory to half an hour, it still seems pretty long. Do you see anything else that might speed it up? I commented out the line that updates the ListView by showing each row as selected so it isn't that. The drag and drop time is 12 minutes so it isn't just a slow laptop either. I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Dharman - When I say the progress isn't being updated, what happens is that it is set to 0 at the start and then stays there until it's completed and then switches to 100.

Comment: Dharman - My mistake. There was a typo that prevented the progress from being updated. It's working fine now though still pretty slow.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin I've tried with 30'000 files (total size around 1 GB). Windows Explorer needed around 50 seconds, my code needed 70 seconds. It's not surprising that the .NET code is slower since it's a managed framework. At the moment I have no idea how to improve it further.

Comment: keco - Thanks for those numbers. I don't know what's going on that it's so slow. I noticed that it did the first 10% (800 files) in about a minute and a half and then each 105 after that took longer and longer. Is this a clue to someone who's smarter than me? (Not a tough qualification to meet) I tried only updating the progress every 50 records but it didn't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: Is there a way you could show me the code that copied the 30K files in 70 seconds? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin It's exactly the code I posted in the answer. My guess was the `CopyFile`method of the `My` namespace, but using the `IO.File` class didn't improve anything.

Comment: "This thread is (like all other threads) very selfish and doesn't care about other threads. It doesn't event know or want to know them. That's the reason why you cannot access any controls that are created in another thread." - No, it's not. That's an incorrect statement and it's not anything like the truth.

Comment: "I'm not a professional, but it seems that `SelectedItems` isn't a real list." - You're not at all correct here. `SelectedItems` is defined at a `class SelectedListViewItemCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`.

Comment: The rest of your answer is excellent, but you go ahead and make a couple of really bad explanations which ruin the whole thing for me.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm sorry. That was my understanding of the things. I updated my answer.